# Can I add Spring model attributes to a redirect using Javascript?

Tags: java, spring

Using attributes and flash attributes on my spring model, I am able to update page elements from my controller like normal. However I am wondering if I can add attributes to my model during a redirect initiated from Javascript?

Currently I'm just using `window.location.replace()` (to prevent back button use) and adding the message I want to send as a URL encoded parameter, but I'm wondering if I can set model attributes directly in Javascript so I wouldn't need endpoints for success and failure and can just send them back to the upload form with a success/failure message added to the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after much testing and research, it seems it is not possible to directly add attributes to a Spring model during a redirect from Javascript because once the server sends the response to the browser, and the browser initiates a redirect, the server-side model is no longer available.

My solution of passing the message as a URL encoded parameter and retrieving it on the server-side using the HttpServletRequest.getParameter() method works fine.

Alternatively, we can use session attributes to store the message on the server-side during the redirect and retrieve it on the subsequent request with HttpSession.setAttribute() and retrieve it on the server-side using the HttpServletRequest.getSession().getAttribute() method. This approach allows us to add attributes to the model during a redirect, but it requires the use of sessions and is not suitable for my use case.

(https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.1.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)